# Creating bootable NTFS partition on Debian

Tags: windows-7, boot, debian, ntfs, multi-boot

I have 2 partitions on my hard drive:

- first one is ext3 formatted with a Debian installation on it (bootable)
- second one is NTFS formatted and was used from a previous Windows installation as logical volume (not bootable)

I would like to install Windows 7 on the NTFS partition. How can I make the NTFS partition bootable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just install Windows(tm) to it.

Note, however, that windows installer will erase your linux bootloader (but this is easily fixed).